# Can someone help me understand the Iterable interface?

Tags: java, class, interface, iterable

I found this code snippet and have been having trouble fully understanding its implementation. I know it has one method:

```
Iterator<T> iterator()
```

which creates a new iterator. But what is the point of this one method. 
In this example:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Range implements Iterable<Integer> {
  private int start, end;
  public Range(int start, int end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return new RangeIterator();
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Range range = new Range(1, 10);
  for(Integer cur : range) {
    System.out.println(cur);
  }
}
```

The code works correctly, yet `iterator()` has never been called. I know you need the `Iterable` interface to use the for each loop, but what is the point of the one method inside the interface? Any help in clearing this confusion would be appreciated.

Comment: It's called implicitly by the enhanced for-loop.

Comment: Exactly as @azurefrog states -- it's called behind the scenes, and that's the main reason for implementing the interface -- to allow use of the for-each loop.

Comment: [Here's a good blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) from oracle discussing these loops, and [here is the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) from the oracle tutorials explaining them.

Comment: Well, know this makes much more sense. Thank you!